# DSS - Endpoints have Ports Appended in the WSDLs, can they be removed?

Tags: wso2

First, thanks for reading.  I hope to have a simple question and if anyone could provide an answer, I would appreciate it.  We are having great success with WSO2 products, but have been struggling with the following.

Setup: DSS has a setup of PortOffset 1 (9444 port usage)

External Load Balancer that listens for https://SOMESERVER and
forwards to DSS Workers on ServerName:9444.  When we create services in DSS, the WSDL will have an appended PORT on the endpoints.  Is there a way to turn off this PORT being added to the WSDL endpoints

```
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="SecureSOAP12Endpoint" binding="ns0:ThisServiceSOAP12Binding">
    <soap12:address location="https://SOMESERVER:9444/services/ThisService.SecureSOAP12Endpoint/"></soap12:address>
</wsdl:port>
```

ESB has Transport options to change WSDL Prefixes.  We do not see the same in DSS and therefore ALL of our URLs have appended port of the carbon port (+offset).

```
   <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!--             Transport Ins (Listeners)             -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->

     <transportReceiver class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener" name="http">
        <parameter locked="false" name="port">8280</parameter>
        <parameter locked="false" name="non-blocking">true</parameter>
        <parameter locked="false" name="bind-address">http://SOMESERVER</parameter>
        <parameter locked="false" name="WSDLEPRPrefix">http://SOMESERVER</parameter>
        <parameter locked="false" name="httpGetProcessor">org.wso2.carbon.transport.nhttp.api.PassThroughNHttpGetProcessor</parameter>
        <parameter locked="false" name="priorityConfigFile">location of priority configuration file</parameter>
    </transportReceiver>

     <transportReceiver class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener" name="https">
        <parameter locked="false" name="port">8243</parameter>
        <parameter locked="false" name="non-blocking">true</parameter>
        <parameter locked="false" name="bind-address">https://SOMESERVER</parameter>
        <parameter locked="false" name="WSDLEPRPrefix">https://SOMESERVER</parameter>
         <parameter locked="false" name="httpGetProcessor">org.wso2.carbon.transport.nhttp.api.PassThroughNHttpGetProcessor</parameter>
```

Comment: got rid of all of the block quote formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. You can try to replace the default listener with NIO listener. There are comments in the axis2.xml file on how to do that
2. Front your DSS instance with an ESB instance. I think this would be a better solution in the long run due to the additional capabilities you can get from it, like failover, load balancing, lightweight service composition and so on.